# Kafka Streams - ensuring state store is up-to-date when producing & consuming to/from the same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application which produces to a Kafka topic and consumes from the same topic. It consumes using a KStream and creates a materialization such that state can be queried. Consider the following scenario:

1. The application produces to the topic.
2. Immediately after producing, it queries the local state store.

Is it possible to guarantee that the state store query will return the state reflected by the message produced in (1)? It seems that there will be a lag in the state store reflecting the true state, since the message must undergo a roundtrip to the topic and back again via the consumer.

Comment: There will be a lag. What is current latency?

Comment: I guess it depends how you do it -- using the Processor API you could write into the state store before to write to the topic, too.